Deriving to a recurrence relation defined as a sum of Stirling numbers
Recently I found this interesting formula connecting Stirling numbers
$$ L(n, k) = \sum_{j=k}^{n} c(n, j) S(j, k) \hspace{2cm}  (1), $$
where $c(n, k) = c(n-1, k-1) + (n-1) c(n-1, k)$ and $S(n, k) = S(n-1, k-1) + k S(n-1, k).$
I also found that the numbers $L(n, k)$ are called Lah numbers and they satisfy the recurrence
$$L(n, k) = L(n-1, k-1) + (n+k-1) L(n-1, k).$$
Just from curiosity: suppose now we only know formula (1) and we want to find the recurrence for $L(n, k)$ using only recurrences for Stirling numbers ($c(n, k) = c(n-1, k-1) + (n-1) c(n-1, k)$ and $S(n, k) = S(n-1, k-1) + k S(n-1, k)).$
My approach woul be something like rewriting  the product $c(n, j) S(j, k)$ using the recurrences for Stirling numbers:
\begin{align*} L(n, k) &= \sum_{j=k}^{n} c(n, j) S(j, k) \\
&= \sum_{j=k}^{n} (c(n-1, j-1) + (n-1) c(n-1, j)) \times (S(j-1, k-1) + k(S(j-1, k))  \\
&= \sum_{j=k}^{n} (c(n-1, j-1) \times S(j-1, k) + c(n-1, j-1) \times kS(j-1, k) + (n-1) c(n-1, j) S(j-1, k-1) + (n-1) c(n-1, j) \times k S(j-1, k)).  \end{align*}
Now I don't know how to continue.
So, question: How to find the recurrence for $L(n, k)$ using only formula (1) and only recurrences for Stirling numbers ($c(n, k) = c(n-1, k-1) + (n-1) c(n-1, k)$ and $S(n, k) = S(n-1, k-1) + k S(n-1, k)).$

I guess in your approach there should be $c(n-1, j-1) \times S(j-1, k{\color{red}-\color{red}1})$ instead of $c(n-1, j-1) \times S(j-1, k)$.

Assuming the recurrences for $S(\cdot,\cdot)$ and $c(\cdot,\cdot)$ are applicable in the transformations below, we obtain
$$L(n, k) = \sum_{j=k}^{n} c(n, j) S(j, k)=$$
$$\sum_{j=k}^{n} (c(n-1, j-1)+(n-1)c(n-1,j))S(j, k)=$$
$$\sum_{j=k}^{n} c(n-1, j-1)S(j, k)+(n-1)\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} c(n-1,j)S(j, k)+ (n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k)=$$
$$\sum_{j=k}^{n} c(n-1, j-1)(S(j-1,k-1)+kS(j-1,k))+(n-1)L(n-1,k)+(n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k)=$$
$$\sum_{j=k}^{n} c(n-1, j-1)S(j-1,k-1)+k\sum_{j=k}^{n} c(n-1, j-1)S(j-1,k)+(n-1)L(n-1,k)+(n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k)=$$
$$\sum_{j=k-1}^{n-1} c(n-1,j)S(j,k-1)+k\sum_{j=k-1}^{n-1} c(n-1, j)S(j,k)+(n-1)L(n-1,k)+ (n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k)=$$
$$L(n-1,k-1)+kc(n-1,k-1)S(k-1,k)+k\sum_{j=k}^{n-1} c(n-1, j)S(j,k)+(n-1)L(n-1,k)+(n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k)=$$
$$L(n-1,k-1)+kc(n-1,k-1)S(k-1,k)+kL(n-1,k)+(n-1)L(n-1,k)+(n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k)=$$
$$L(n-1,k-1)+kc(n-1,k-1)S(k-1,k)+(n+k-1)L(n-1,k)+ (n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k).$$
This is almost the required equality, but we have to have $$kc(n-1,k-1)S(k-1,k)+(n-1)c(n-1,n)S(n,k)=0.$$
I expect this equality holds, because, as I understood, you consider Stirling numbers $S(n,k)$ of the
second kind, which satisfy the same
recurrence relation,
so $S(n,k)=0$ when $n<k$. The coefficients $c(n, j)$ are used when $k\le j\le n$, which suggests that
$c(n-1,n)=0$.

This is perhaps not what is being asked, but nonetheless it's a quick way to derive formula (1) in the question. We can consider the infinite lower triangular matrices $(c(n,k))_{n\ge k\ge 0}$ and $(S(n,k))_{n\ge k\ge 0}$ as exponential Riordan arrays, i.e. as encoded by an ordered pair of functions $(g,f)=(g(x),f(x))$ so that the exponential generating function of the sequence in column $k$ is $\dfrac{gf^k}{k!}$. Then
$$
\left(c(n,k)\right)_{n\ge k\ge 0}=\left(1,\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right), \quad \left(S(n,k)\right)_{n\ge k\ge 0}=\left(1,e^x-1\right), \quad \left(L(n,k)\right)_{n\ge k\ge 0}=\left(1,\frac{x}{1-x}\right).
$$
Since the first component is $1$ in all these cases (only the empty permutation has $0$ cycles, and only the empty partition has $0$ parts), the second component is just the e.g.f. for $k=1$ (cyclic permutations, or partitions with a single part, unordered or ordered, respectively).
For exponential (or ordinary) Riordan arrays $(g,f)$ and $(G,F)$, we have the following multiplication law:
$$
(g,f)(G,F)=(g\cdot(G\circ f), F\circ f)=(g(x)G(f(x)), F(f(x))).
$$
Therefore,
$$
\left(1,\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)\right)\left(1,e^x-1\right)=\left(1,e^{\log\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)}-1\right)=\left(1,\dfrac{1}{1-x}-1\right)=\left(1,\frac{x}{1-x}\right).
$$
